# How to find the max of each "slice" in a multidimensional matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, max, multidimensional-array

I have an n-dimensional matrix Q. I can find the max values through
the last dimension by:

```
m = max(Q,[],n).
```

However, I do not know how to find the max values through the last
"slice". I need something "like"

```
m = max(Q,[],n-1,n).
```

For example, if I have

```
A(:,:,1) = [1 2 3 ; 4 50 6]
A(:,:,2) = [9 8 7 ; 10 12 1]
```

I would like to have `m = [9 50]`.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a double call to max:

```
m = max(max(A, [], 3), [], 2)
```